# Object data from Firebase is Undefined regardless of using Async and Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from different collections in my cloud Firestore database in advance before I process them and apply them to batch, I created two async functions, one to capture the data and another to execute certain code only after all data is collected, I didn't want the code executing and creating errors before the data is fetched when i try to access the matchesObject after the async function to collect data is finished, it keeps saying "it cannot access a property matchStatus of undefined", matchStatus is a field in my object, after a while, i see the data showing all the documents saved to matchObjects and the document i want is there, I logged the data being saved to the matches object, it retrieves all the data and I can confirm that the document I am looking for is fetched from firestore, it's like the code doesn't wait for the object to be finished before it runs, or something, i thought took care of that with async and await? could anyone shed some light as to why it is undefined one moment

```
axios.request(options).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Total matches count :' + response.data.matches.length);

  const data = response.data;
  var matchesSnapshot;
  var marketsSnapshot;
  var tradesSnapshot;
  var betsSnapshot;

  matchesObject = {};
  marketsObject = {};
  tradesObject = {};
  betsObject = {};

  start();

  async function checkDatabase() {
    matchesSnapshot = await db.collection('matches').get();
    matchesSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      matchesObject[doc.id] = doc.data();
      console.log('matches object: ' + doc.id.toString())
    });

    marketsSnapshot = await db.collection('markets').get();
    marketsSnapshot.forEach(doc2 => {
      marketsObject[doc2.id] = doc2.data();
      console.log('markets object: ' + doc2.id.toString())
    });

    tradesSnapshot = await db.collection('trades').get();
    tradesSnapshot.forEach(doc3 => {
      tradesObject[doc3.id] = doc3.data();
      console.log('trades object: ' + doc3.id.toString())
    });

    betsSnapshot = await db.collection('bets').get();
    betsSnapshot.forEach(doc4 => {
      betsObject[doc4.id] = doc4.data();
      console.log('bets object: ' + doc4.id.toString())
    });
  }


  async function start() {
    await checkDatabase();
    // this is the part which is undefined, it keeps saying it cant access property matchStatus of undefined
    console.log('here is matches object  ' + matchesObject['302283']['matchStatus']);

    if (Object.keys(matchesObject).length != 0) {
      for (let bets of Object.keys(betsObject)) {

        if (matchesObject[betsObject[bets]['tradeMatchId']]['matchStatus'] == 'IN_PLAY' && betsObject[bets]['matched'] == false) {
          var sfRef = db.collection('users').doc(betsObject[bets]['user']);
          batch11.set(sfRef, {
            accountBalance: admin.firestore.FieldValue + parseFloat(betsObject[bets]['stake']),
          }, {
            merge: true
          });

          var sfRef = db.collection('bets').doc(bets);
          batch12.set(sfRef, {
            tradeCancelled: true,
          }, {
            merge: true
          });
        }
      }
     
     }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed on how firebase works. For fetch data use something like this

```
    const getWithKey= async({
    collection, value, orderBy = 'asc', where = 'id', operationString = '=='
  }) => {
    if (idControl(value)) {
      const data = await db.collection(collection)
        .where(where, operationString, value).get();
      if (data?.docs[0]) {
        return [data.docs[0].data()];
      }
    }

    const documents = [];
    await db
      .collection(collection)
      .orderBy(where, orderBy)
      .get()
      .then((item) => {
        item.forEach((doc) => {
          documents.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });
      });
    return documents || [];
  }
```

Comment: could you please explain your approach, when I copied it to my code to use it, it said the async  getWithKey is missing a semicolon just before the open brace and if statement begin

Comment: I copied this piece of code from my some special class, then now after your comment, I fixed my answer for constant func, can u try again?

Comment: thanks, let me try, whats that part called 'idControl' used to do?

Comment: if you past some value, its mean you searching in database like get value product which id=1, otherwise you getting all collection. After all, can u vote my answer? :)